# BigQuery - Extract certain columns from a repeated and nested field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table structure:

```
|       Field name         |    Type    |    Mode    |
-----------------------------------------------------
message_info               |   RECORD   |  NULLABLE  |
  |-destination            |   RECORD   |  REPEATED  |
      |-address            |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-service            |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-selector           |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-smime_signature    |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-smime_decryption   |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-smime_parsing      |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
      |-smime_extraction   |   STRING   |  NULLABLE  |
```

I want to keep the `RECORD` and `REPEATED` nature from the `destination` field, but I only want to retrieve the first three nested fields, as I do not need the smime ones.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
    STRUCT(
        d.address AS address,
        d.service AS service,
        d.selector AS selector
    ) AS destination
FROM
    `myproject.mydataset.mytable` AS mail,
    UNNEST(mail.message_info.destination) AS d
```

However, this does not preserve the `REPEATED` nature of the `message_info.destination` field. If I add an `ARRAY_AGG()` statement like this:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
        d.address AS address,
        d.service AS service,
        d.selector AS selector
    )) AS destination
FROM
    `myproject.mydataset.mytable` AS mail,
    UNNEST(mail.message_info.destination) AS d
```

I get an error message stating that it conflicts with other not repeated fields I am retrieving: `SELECT list expression references mail.event_info.timestamp_usec which is neither grouped nor aggregated`.

What is the correct way of retrieving these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select mail.*,
       (select array_agg(struct(d.address AS address,
                                d.service AS service,
                                d.selector AS selector
                               )
                        )
        from unnest(mail.message_info.destination) d
       ) as new_destination
from `myproject.mydataset.mytable` mail;
```

This creates `new_destination` for each row in the original table.  When you use `array_agg()` in the outer query with no aggregation, you are aggregating over all rows -- so you cannot select other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach.
While approaches in other answer(s) destroy original table's schema - this one fully preserves it

```
select * replace(
    (select as struct * 
       replace(array(select as struct address, service, selector from mi.destination) as destination)
     from unnest([message_info]) mi
    ) as message_info
  ) 
from `myproject.mydataset.mytable` t
```